# Rails 3- how can I access a parameter passed to a new action in a create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

So I have the following link which passes a parameter experience_id to the new action of an experience_skills controller.

```
<%= button_to 'Add Skill', new_experience_skill_path(:experience_id => experience.id),:remote => "true", :class => "btn", :id => "new-experience-skill-btn" %>
```

This works out just fine-- i.e. params[:experience_id] is the right value!

The problem is that I need to access params[:experience_id]  in my create action of the experience_skills controller in order for some javascript and ajax to function correctly.

How can I access the parameter passed to the new action within the create action???

Thank you for your help in advance. 
And of course if you give me the right answer, I will accept it as so.
-Alex

Comment: No it does not. I've tried it already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

which place you trying to access the params[:experience_id] ? in new action or create action?

in your form,you can do like this ,Example:

```
   <div class="field">    
       <%= f.hidden_field :experience_id, :value => @instant_obj.id %>
   </div>
```

then, in your controller in new action

```
 @instant_obj = CLASS.find(params[:experience_id])
```

nt sure it can help u ..

Modified:
if not mistaken, it will only at New, lets said from my scenario, in the new controller of Message, it need the advertisement_id which is the hidden field, in order to create Message, it need advertisement_id as well, so, i 'll do

```
@advertisement = Advertisement.find(params[:advertisement_id])
@message = Message.new(:advertisement_id => @advertisement.id)
```

then when I saved my Message model (which is in the create action controller), it will save all the detail.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm trying to access the value within the create action. Will this logic pass the parameter to create as well or only to new?

Comment: if not mistaken, it will only at New, lets said from my scenario,

Comment: But how could i pass the parameter to the create action? That's what I need to do.

Comment: ahh yes of course. I have access to the experience id once it's saved!!! Thanks for pointing that out @Nich. you the man.

Answer (score 0):

You can send this value from hidden fields if you use form in new.